# Средства модульного программирования

Tags: javascript

Дали задание, решаемое (вроде как) в пару строк кода. 
Условие звучит так:

> Средствами модульного программирования решить задачу обработки
>   одномерного числового массива. Найти количество элементов, кратных
>   заданному числу и не попавших в интервал [a,b].

Решил задачу так:

```js
function calc(array, a, b, k){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] < a || array[i] > b ){
            if (array[i] % k == 0) {
                console.log(array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
calc([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3, 5, 2);
```

Но вот что в данном случае значат "средства модульного программирования" и как, в таком случае, надо решать это задание?

Comment: Если верить википедии: [Роль модулей могут играть структуры данных, библиотеки функций, классы, сервисы и др. программные единицы, реализующие некоторую функциональность и предоставляющие интерфейс к ней.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) Так что, выделение функции, вполне можно считать использованием средств модульного программирования. Но точно ответить на данный вопрос может только тот, кто его задал.

Comment: @Grundy ясно спасибо.. просто ещё больше модульности для столь короткого кода я не представляю себе)

Comment: В данном случае это просто задача, для того чтобы научиться разбивать код на подзадачи видимо. Ну либо вам нужно сделать что-то вроде знаменитого [left-pad](https://github.com/stevemao/left-pad/blob/master/index.js). Например, можно в отдельную функцию/файл вынести проверку кратности, проверку попадания в интервал.